# UIButtons located in a UIView underneath interfering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UIScrollView` over the main view of the view controller. `UIScrollView` contains some `UIButtons` (detail disclosure type) and a `floating UIView` -- all managed by only one view controller.

The `floating UIView` also contains its own UIButtons (custom, not rounded type). User is allowed to hide the `floating UIView`, or move it to a new location.

I found that the `UIButtons` contained in the UIScrollView (parent) are interfering with (preventing) tapping of the `UIButtons` contained in the `floating UIView` whenever these UIButtons overlap. If partially overlapped, only the overlapped area is a dead zone. I tried explicitly bringing the `floating UIView` to the front by issuing this message:

```
[self.myScrollView bringSubviewToFront:myFloatingView];
```

-but the problem does not go away.

The interference goes away if I keep the `UIButtons` of the parent hidden. But, this is not what I want.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

A button can not interfere in the way you described.  I think it something else.

All of the times I have had similar issue have been because subviews were taken outside the bounds of their parent views.  The rule is:

**If a subview is outside of its parent view's bounds it will not receive touch events.**

This isnt explicitly stated in the docs but you can infer it by reading sections of the [touch event guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541).

I think what *might* be happening is that you are moving the floating UIView outside of its parent bounds.

It might not be it, its just a suggestion.

Comment: Robert, All subviews are within the parent's bounds.I narrowed down the problem. The dead zone at the overlapped area occurs ONLY if I use the following types of UIButtons on the parent view: Detail disclosure and info. No problem at all with the regular & custom UIButtons with or without image!